# C# Core Get Generic Class T of Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I know how to loop through all properties of a class, but what if on property are List, how can I loop through all properties of T class? See comments in my code. I have read 20 of the suggested similar questions but I don't get any answer. Either I am stupid and this is a duplicate (sorry for that in that case) or the answer is needed.

```
public class HeaderClass
{
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }  
    public string HeaderText2 { get; set; } 
    public RowClass Rows { get; set; }  
}

public class RowClass
{
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public int SubRowId { get; set; }
    public string SubText { get; set; } 
    public string SubText2 { get; set; }    
}

//Call this to get all properties of HeaderClass
Getdata(Headers);

void Getdata(object myObject)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        string currentPropertyName = pi.Name;
        string currentPropertyType;

        //First of all, are there a better way to direct get the TypeName?
        if(pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            currentPropertyType = "string";
        }
        else if(pi.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || pi.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
        {
            currentPropertyType = "bool";
        }
        else if(pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            currentPropertyType = "DateTime";
        }


        //If the Type is List<T>
        if(pi.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() == "list`1")
        {
            Type itemType = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            //How to convert this to an object so I can loop through all properties of class SubRows
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all properties of list type like this

```cs
if(pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && !pi.PropertyType.Name.Equals("Nullable`1"))
// or if(pi.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() == "list`1")
{
    foreach (var property in pi.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]
           .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
                             // BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly => Inherited members are not considered
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not check the name, use `pt.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)`, second try this:

```
class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}

class Bar
{
    public int I1 { get; set; }
    public string S1 { get; set; }
}

var x = new Foo
{
    Bars = new List<Bar> { new Bar { S1 = "asdd"}}
};
foreach (var prop in typeof(Foo).GetProperties())
{

    var pt = prop.PropertyType;
    if (pt.IsGenericType && pt.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    {
        var en = (prop.GetValue(x) as IEnumerable).Cast<object>();

        var innerType = pt.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        foreach (var innerProp in innerType.GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(innerProp.Name); // prints I1 S1
            Console.WriteLine(innerProp.GetValue(en.First())); // prints "asdd"
        }
    }
}
```

*How to convert this to an object so I can loop thrue all properties of class SubRows*

So you don't need to convert it to object, `pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]` returns you an instance of `Type` which has `.GetProperties()` method on it.

Comment: but if its not converted to an object, can I still get the value of the property? Like pi.GetValue(myObject)

Comment: @Vekonomen in my code you will need to call `var propObj  = pt.GetValue()` and then `innerProp.GetValue(propObj)`

Comment: If I type var propObj  = pt.GetValue() direct after var pt = prop.PropertyType; I get error Type does not contain a definition for GetValue and no accessible method GetValue acceptng a first argument of type Type...

Comment: @Vekonomen, sorry not `pt` but `prop.GetValue(myObject)`

Comment: No, that gives me Rows.count=3 as I assume its the object List<T> not the object T?

Comment: now were getting close, but it is still hardkoded (var en=prop.GetValue(x). In a dynamic way you cant specify x right? In your updated post you should pass x in the loop and get the asdd value anyway.

Comment: @Vekonomen `x` can be parameter of your method (e.g. `myObject`), is it dynamic enough?  Or  had I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
static void GetData(object myObject)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        string currentPropertyType;

        Console.WriteLine(pi.Name);

        //First of all, are there a better way to direct get the TypeName?
        if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            currentPropertyType = "string";
        }
        else if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || pi.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
        {
            currentPropertyType = "bool";
        }
        else if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            currentPropertyType = "DateTime";
        }

        // **view the next section...**
    }
}
```

To get the generic type definition of the property type and compare it with List<>

```cs
// If the Type is List<T>
// To check if the type of the property is List<>, we have to first get its
// generic type definition then we can compare it with List<>. 
// If we get null (maybe because we have not a generic type) we avoid the 
// comparison with List<> and the condition is false. If we get it, 
// we compare and if the types match, we can call GetData on the list's items.
if (GetGenericTypeDefinition(pi.PropertyType)?.Equals(typeof(List<>)) ?? false)
{
    Type itemType = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var myListObject = (IEnumerable<object>)pi.GetValue(myObject);

    foreach (var item in myListObject)
    {
        GetData(item);
    }              
}
```

This is the implementation of the method GetGenericTypeDefinition

```cs
static Type GetGenericTypeDefinition(Type type)
{
    // If type is not a generic type we can't get its generic definition so we return null
    if (!type.IsGenericType)
        return null;

    return type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
}
```

I've included a little Main method to test my implementation easily.

```cs
class Class1
{
    public int Val { get; set; }

    public List<Class2> Items { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Class1 obj = new Class1
    {
        Val = 2,
        Items = new List<Class2>
        {
            new Class2
            {
                Val1 = 15,
                Val2 = 22
            },
            new Class2
            {
                Val1 = 107,
                Val2 = 87
            },
            new Class2
            {
                Val1 = 44,
                Val2 = 18
            }
        }

    };

    GetData(obj);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @claudiom248!

But I get the value for the propertys name with pi.Name, but how can I get the value for the value (Like obj.Items[1].Val2 = 2
For a value in the Class1 I can get it like pi.GetValue(myObject) (ignore the typecasting here), thats why I wanted it as  an object.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my solution in order to iterate on the items on the list and showing the object's value with pi.GetValue(item).

Comment: Thanks again Claudiom248
I cant get the value for obj.Items[1].Val2 = 2, I just get that obj.Items = 3 rows.
We are getting closer, let me explain the final goal then it makes a little bit more relevant.
My Class1 and Class2 are having much more properties and I need to create an JSON of the data.
I know about serialize it but my API I gonna send to only accept properties having data that should be set.

Comment: So I can't set all generic class as JSON, I Have to iterate thrue all properties to build my JSON with only the values that isn't null.
Lets say I set it up as
    new Class2
    {
      Val1 = 44,
      Val2 = null
    }
then only the JSON should only contain "Val1" : "44" and nothing more.
This is easy for the Class1, but I can't figure out how to do it for the Class2 rows...

//Peter